# Calling method in host from gridview adapter

Tags: java, android

I have a gridview that is filled with several images using a custom adapter.

The adapter item that shows the images have a download button.

What I want to do is to send a method to the custom adaptar that should be called when the user presses the download button.

In summary:
onlinegallery-> associate gridview with adapter sending an onlinegallery method as parameter
gridview adapter -> shows several item.xml each containing an image and a button.
item button -> when pressing the button, the onlinegallery method should be called indicating the image to download.

Answer (score 0):

write view.onclickListener in custom adapter then set it using button.ssetonclickListener(listener) in getView overrided method .

whenever you want to pass index specific data to listener, create inner class which implements view.onclickListener , then pass data through constructer .....
or use setTag()/getTag()